# How to separate text and links from an input textarea using a jsp page?

Tags: html, jsp

I´m really bad at programming, and I´m trying to do a web aplication using html and jsp pages, the application have to allows the users to post things, and well that is the problem, because I can´t separate text and links from the textarea.

There is the method to post.

```
   <div id ="post">
     <form method="post" action="Validaciones.jsp" >
       <textarea name="comentario" rows="4" cols="20" maxlength="140" id="coment" > 
       </textarea>
       <button name="publicar" value="publicar">Publicar</button> 
     </form>
   </div>
```

But so, when I do:

```
String texto = request.getParameter("comentario");
```

It return the parameter as a String, so if a put, "Hello visit my page: www.ducks.com", there is a way to know what is text and what is the link?
Because the aplication have to show the links as links, with the (a) tag.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Either you should use a proper text editor and avoid using text area OR use Regular Expression to separate the link from the text

Answer (score 0):

Dont use plain textarea.You need to use editors like CKEditor,TinyMce(to name a few).

These editors help to maintain the text formatting and save it into the database.So when you view this on another page you will be able to see whatever you had written earlier in the editor.Hence these editors are called **WYSIWYG (What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get)**

So use these editors in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0‌​-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String toMatch = "this is a URL http://google.com";
Matcher m = p.matcher(toMatch);
```

With the url , use substring for the string.